# Qt Can't find std library for a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, standard-library, std

I have a project in Qt which was working. Then once I shut down creator, opened it back up and rebuilt the project, Qt now says it can't find any of the std library headers. The error message is:

> `D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:45: error:
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory`

(Along with all the other std library headers I used)

I am building with vs 2015, and it would seem like Qt is not setting up the VS environment, but here's the thing, my other projects (in the same directory) build just fine. I have tried deleting the .pro files and the build files, re configuring the project, as well as reinstalling Qt, and running Qt from the command line. All to no avail.

I would just like to know what/where in the Qt environment is VS setup and what could cause only one project to behave this way? I assumed it would be in the Makefile, but I couldn't see anything when I went through it.

The entire compile output is:

`10:13:03: Running steps for project QARD_Viewer...
10:13:03: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:13:03: Starting: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" 
    "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQWT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBENGINE_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINEWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINECORE_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WEBCHANNEL_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I..\QARD_Viewer -I. -I"D:/Users/JSendall/Documents/PCL/GUI/QARD_Viewer/../PXGFtoFile/AARD Backup" -ID:/Users/JSendall/Documents/PCL/GUI/QARD_Viewer/../SIMD_vectors/SIMD_vectors -I"D:/Users/JSendall/Documents/PCL/GUI/QARD_Viewer/../PCL Proc Server/Common files" -ID:\Devlibs\boost_1_62_0 -ID:\Devlibs\Qwt-6.1.3\include -I..\..\Deployment\Code\PXGF_socket\PXGF_socket -I..\..\Deployment\Code\QardDetector\cfarLib -I..\..\Deployment\Code\coordHandling\coordHandling -I"..\..\Deployment\Code\PXGFtoFile\AARD Backup" -I"..\..\Deployment\Code\PCL Proc Server\Common files" -I..\..\Deployment\Code\SIMD_vectors\SIMD_vectors -I..\..\Deployment\Code\pxgf_rpk_client\pxgf_rpk_client -I..\..\Deployment\Code\QardDetector\QardDetector -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWebEngine -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWebEngineWidgets -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWebEngineCore -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtQuick -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtSvg -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWebChannel -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtQml -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtNetwork -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -ID:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\JSendell\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6F02.tmp
main.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
mainwindow.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
ardplot_t.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
qread.cpp
..\..\Deployment\Code\PCL Proc Server\Common files\QARDHeader.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstdint': No such file or directory
cfarplotter.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
detectiondisplay.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
geocode_data_manager.cpp
D:\Devlibs\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
cacfdetector.cpp
..\..\Deployment\Code\QardDetector\cfarLib\caCfarDetector.h(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'numeric': No such file or directory
label_connected.cpp
d:\users\jsendall\documents\pcl\gui\qard_viewer\label_connected.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vector': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
10:13:04: The process "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project QARD_Viewer (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "Make"
10:13:04: Elapsed time: 00:01.`

Comment: are you building from the Qt creator or Visual Studio with Qt addin?

Comment: Can you show your entire "Compile Output" from QtCreator?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm building from creator. And I edited he question to include the compiler output. Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you checked your env INCLUDE variable, does it contain something like "<Path to your programm folder>\Visual Studio 2015\VC\include"? (You can check it on Projects tab of Qt Creator, there is a "Build Environment" at bottom).

Comment: How did you install Qt? How did you configure Qt Creator's compilers, Qt versions, and kits?

Comment: @Rinold Thanks, yea the INCLUDE, LIBS, and basically all the VS/Qt environment variables were missing. So I would have to have manually filled in all the system variables. Anyway, long story short, I reinstalled my entire dev environment and its working, but your comment helped me realize that it wasn't something in my project so thanks!